# How to do a parameter search in Prolog?

Tags: database, search, prolog

For example, a have a "database" like this:

```
processor(pentium_g4400) :-
    brand('intel'),
    family('pentium'),
    series('g4400'),
    clock(3.3),
    socket('lga1151'),
    ram('ddr4'),
    cores(2),
    threads(2),!.
```

If I, for instance, would like to search for 'pentium' family only, or 'lga1151' processors.

Comment: This is not how you state facts in Prolog.

Comment: What is the purpose of the cut in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is *not* a database. What you here have written is:

> `pentium_g4400` is a `processor`, given `'intel'` is a brand, `'pentium'` is a `family`, `'g4400'` is a series, etc.

A database is a set of facts. So you can write it as:

```
processor(pentium_g4400,'intel','pentium','g4400',3.3,'lga1151','ddr4',2,2).
```

Now you can query for processors of the `'pentium'` family for instance with:

```
processor(Proc, _, 'pentium', _, _, _, _, _, _).
```

Where `_` means that you are not interested in the result (you can use variables if you want to know these facts as well).

This approach can of course be inconvenient if some attributes are optional, etc. You can also add a list of terms to every processor, like:

```
processor(pentium_g4400, [brand('intel'),    family('pentium'),
                          series('g4400'),   clock(3.3),
                          socket('lga1151'), ram('ddr4'),
                          cores(2),          threads(2)]).
```

In that case you can query with:

```
processor(Proc, Specs), member(family('pentium'), Specs).
```

So now we look for a processor `Proc` such that `family('pentium')` is a member of the `Specs` list.